# What is the word for a shop that sells small electronic parts (such as LEDs, resistors, transistors, breadboards, etc.)?

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to find stores in Tokyo that sell articles mentioned in the title.

Comment: While this is strictly speaking a translation request, I kind of don’t mind it since it’s not a dictionary term and as such is more of a word choice question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they are usually just called 電子部品屋/電子パーツ屋/電子部品ショップ/電子パーツショップ, i.e., literally 'electronic parts shop'. (I suppose you have in mind those shops found a lot in [Akihabara](https://www.google.com/maps/search/%E7%A7%8B%E8%91%89%E5%8E%9F+%E9%9B%BB%E5%AD%90%E9%83%A8%E5%93%81+%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%83%E3%83%97/@35.7011396,139.7671158,16z/data=!3m1!4b1) - not sure the link works.)

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot!